# How to run django and wordpress with nginx

Tags: django, wordpress, nginx

I'm having problem with configuring my `nginx.conf` file to run django server on main domain and a WordPress site on `domain.com/blog`.

This is my configuration file which my WordPress `dir` is 
`/var/www/varzesh-kon/blog/`:

```
upstream Main_Project_server {
server unix:/home/amirfarsad/django_env/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

  listen   80;
  server_name 2n9l.s.serverhost.name;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  access_log /home/amirfarsad/logs/nginx-access.log;
  error_log /home/amirfarsad/logs/nginx-error.log;

  location /static/ {
      alias   /home/amirfarsad/Main_Project/static/;
  }

  location /media/ {
      alias   /home/amirfarsad/Main_Project/media/;
  }

  location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      if (!-f $request_filename) {
          proxy_pass http://Main_Project_server;
          break;
      }
  }


  location /blog/ {
      root /var/www/varzesh-kon/blog/;
      index index.php index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
      root /var/www/varzesh-kon/blog/;
  }
}
```

My django site works well but when I go to `domain.com/blog`, it gives me a 404 not found nginx page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your bottom `location block`

```
location ^~ /blog {
        root /var/www/varzesh-kon/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

Explanation:
In case of the `root` directive, full path is appended to the root including the location part

In your case:

```
location /blog/ {
      root /var/www/varzesh-kon/blog/;
```

The final path that nginx will derive is going to be:

```
/var/www/varzesh-kon/blog/blog
```

That's why its showing you `404 not found` page

---

**Solution**:
Either use `alias` instead of `root`

or change root path to `/var/www/varzesh-kon/`

```
location /blog/ {
      root /var/www/varzesh-kon/;
...
}

location /blog/ {
      alias /var/www/varzesh-kon/blog/;
...
}
```

for more: [wiki](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)

Comment: nice explanation

Comment: Very useful explanation
The problem of 404 page is now solved but I'm experiencing another issue
PHP files are downloading instead of opening in browser do you know how can I solve it?

Comment: You can follow this guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04